# Oracle sql query with complex constraint

Tags: sql, oracle

Table named **T1** with following values

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
Rs1     S       S2
Rs2     SX      S3
Rs3     S       S2
```

From a csv, I need to insert some values into the table, having values Rs4, SX and S3 respectively to each column.

I need to apply a check with following constraints.

- One S3 can belong to only one SX, but S3 and SX as pair can belong can belong to multiple columns1's values.

What will be the oracle query for this? And if the above condition is true then I need to run an insertion query which is prepared. How can it validated?

PS: we can't create another table.

Comment: Why are they in the same table then? What normalization strategy led to that? Also, have you considered a stored proc for this kind of special insertion?

Comment: It is a requirement which states it, that it col3's value can belong or combined with with one col2's value but can be combined with multiple col1's value. Yes i'm working on the Stored procedure only, its just one constraint from one of those.

Comment: What about a trigger containing something like this:  IF :new.col2 IN (select col2 from T1) AND (:new.col3 NOT IN (select col2 from T1 where col2 = :new.col2)) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000, 'INSERT DENIED');
  END IF;`

Comment: It will be recommended if there is some query instead of a trigger, so as to not make the stored procedure more complex and time consuming as csv file can be large in size.

Comment: col3's value can only belong to col2's value only one time and can be inserted myriad of times with any col1's value.

Comment: @clifton_h, I was not in dilemma with triggers and SP, its just that, triggers if included in the SP make it more complex. Thats why, I prefer for a query

Comment: You did not give us the necessary business requirements, essentially wasting time. Please help us help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I'm able to resolve the question with a some select queries and few if conditions being applied. I have done this in a stored procedure.

```
  SELECT count(col3) 
  INTO V_exist_value
  FROM T3 
  WHERE col3's value = Variable_col3
  AND col1's value <> Variable_col1 
  AND col2's value = Variable_col2;

  IF (V_exist_value >= 1) THEN     
      INSERT INTO T3 (col1, col2, col3)
      VALUES (Variable_col1, Variable_col2, Variable_col3);
  ELSE 
      SELECT count(col3) 
      INTO V_exist_value1 
      FROM T3 
      WHERE col3's value = Variable_col3;

      IF (V_exist_value1 = 0) THEN
        INSERT INTO T3 (col1, col2, col3)
      VALUES (Variable_col1, Variable_col2, Variable_col3);
  ELSE 
        RAISE Exception_col3_value_exists;
      END IF;

  END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

*Had to do a little discovery after I was informed that I totally missed the ORACLE tag. Knowing what you do not know is very important to me. This post should be sufficiently different.*

**THE BASIC PROBLEM WITH ORACLE'S CHECK**

> - A check constraint can NOT be defined on a SQL View. The check constraint defined on a table must refer to only columns in that
>     table. It can not refer to columns in other tables.
> - A check constraint can NOT include a SQL Subquery.
> - A check constraint can be defined in either a SQL CREATE TABLE statement or a SQL ALTER TABLE statement.

**REVISITING THE PROBLEM**

- We know that (Col2,Col3)| #(Col2,COl3) >= 1.
- We know that {Col1}∩(Col2,Col3)
- However, the #Cardinality of Col1? Can it be more than 1?

**Clearly, the business requirements are not fully explained.**

**REVISITING THE SOLUTIONS**

1. **Adding Objects to the database.**

While adding additional tables has been voted down, is it possible to add an ID column? Assuming Col1 is NOT unique to the subsets of (Col2,COl3), then you can add a true ID Column that fulfills the need for normalization while providing true indexing power in your query.

```
Col1    Col2    Col3  Col4
Rs1     S       S2    1
Rs2     SX      S3    2
Rs3     S       S2    1
```

To be clear, Col4 would still be an ID since the values of Col2, Col3 are determined by Col4. `(Col2,Col3) 1:1 Col4`.

2. **CHECKS**

> - Multiple CHECK constraints, each with a simple condition enforcing a
>     single business rule, are preferable to a single CHECK constraint with
>     a complicated condition enforcing multiple business rules [ORACLE - Constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#i1002719)
> - A single column can have multiple CHECK constraints that reference the
>     column in its definition. There is no limit to the number of CHECK
>     constraints that you can define on a column. [ORACLE - Data Integrity](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/data_int.htm#i11423)

If you can add a column...*by the love of monkeys*, please do...not only will it make your life much easier, but you can also make QUERYING the table very efficient. However, for the rest of this post, **I will assume you cannot add columns**:

**RESTATING THE PROBLEM IN CONSTRAINTS**

- Col2 may not appear with a different Col3. Vice Versa.
- (Col2,Col3) may have multiple Co1...what is the possible Cardinality of Col1? Can it be repetitive? **I read no**.

**WRITING OUT THE THEORY ON CHECKS**

IF Col1 truly is unique in {(col2,col3)}, then the following already works:

```
ALTER TABLE EXAMPLE3
ADD CONSTRAINT ch_example3_3way  UNIQUE (C, D, X) --only works if these valus never repeat.
```

- The other main constraint #(Col2,Col3) > 1 simply cannot work unless you knew what value was being entered so as to enforce a real `SARG`. Any `Col1 = Col1` or `Col1 IN Col1` is the same thing as writing 1 = 1.

**ON TRIGGERS**

- As tempting as the idea sounds, a quick glance through `ORACLE` lane left me warning against the use. Some reasons from `ORACLE`:

> [ORACLE - USING TRIGGERS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm)
>
> - Do not create recursive triggers.
>     For example, if you create an AFTER UPDATE statement trigger on the
>     employees table, and the trigger itself issues an UPDATE statement on
>     the employees table, the trigger fires recursively until it runs out
>     of memory.
> - Use triggers on DATABASE judiciously. They are executed for every user every time the event occurs on which the trigger is created
>
> Other problems include: [TOADWORLD - ORACLE WIKI](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/5806.trigger-disadvantages)
>
> - Not Compiled -*STORED PROCs can reuse a cached plan*
> - No SELECT Trigger Support
> - Complete Trigger Failure
> - Disabled Triggers
> - No Version Control
> - Update OF COLUMN
> - No Support of SYS Table Triggers
> - Mutating Triggers
> - Hidden Behavior

Still, there are advantages of `TRIGGER`s, and you could still enforce data integrity by using a query where the first result of

`SELECT Col2, Col3 FROM T1 WHERE ROWNUM = 1`

Is compared to the inserted value *new.*Col2, *new.*Col3, but this would require the trigger to fire **EVERY TIME** a row was inserted...recompiled and everything,..I STRONGLY URGE AVOIDANCE.

**STORED PROCS**

Whatever you may think of `STORED PROCEDURES`, I suggest you consider them again. Everything from `Function`s, `DML`, `DDL`, `database management`, `RECURSIVE LOGIC`, `sp_executesql`, and beyond can be accomplished through a `PROC`.

- Easily managed, provides encapsulation from accidental or malicious disabling or mutilization of coding.
- `PROC`s are compiled once and can be reuse query plan caches, providing improved performances.
- Provides superior portability, can be **embedded into** `TRIGGERS`, `ORM` framework, applications and beyond.
- Can literally automate almost any function in a database including `ETL`, `Resource management`, security, and discovery. `Views` are commonly run through stored Procs.

**THE UNIQUE ADVANTAGE OF ORACLE**

Perhaps forgotten, consider that this is ORACLE which allows you to suspend `CONSTRAINTS` by inserting in the `CONSTRAINT` `DEFFERABLE`. From an `ETL` specialist perspective, this is essentially making a staging table out of your only table...which is pretty sweet in your predicament of having limited `DDL` rights.

**CONCLUDING COMMENTS**

There are a few efficient methods to delete duplicates in your data.

```
DELETE FROM T1
WHERE rowid NOT IN
            (SELECT MAX(rowid)
             FROM T1
             GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3);
```

- **NOTE:** rowid is the physical location of the row, while rownum represents the logical position in the query.

**Lastly, my last attempt at rowid. Unfortunately, time is running late, and the free COMPILER from ORACLE is unhelpful. But I think the idea is what is important.**

```
CREATE TABLE Example3 (MUT VARCHAR(50), D VARCHAR(50), X VARCHAR(50) );

INSERT INTO Example3 (MUT, D, X) VALUES('MUT', 'T', 'M' );
INSERT INTO Example3 (MUT, D, X) VALUES('MUT', 'T', 'P' );
INSERT INTO Example3 (MUT, D, X) VALUES('MUT', 'X', 'LP');
INSERT INTO Example3 (MUT, D, X) VALUES('MUT', 'X', 'Z');
INSERT INTO Example3 (MUT, D, X) VALUES('MUT', 'Y', 'POP');

SELECT C.D, B.X, B.rowid
FROM EXAMPLE3 A
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT X, C.rowid
            FROM EXAMPLE3) B ON B.rowid = A.rowid
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                             SELECT DISTINCT D, MAX(rowid) AS [rowid]
                             FROM Example3) C ON C.rowid = B.rowid
```

Comment: I know this problem seems to be knotty enough, that's why I have seek for help. I need to analyze, CHECK constraint on the table, which I will revert soon. Secondly, I will also try adding triggers if CHECK doesn't work. But, to be honest, this not the solution which I need. Firstly, I need work on one single table. In addition to above, I have already applied a unique constraint on all the 3 columns, which is needed as requirement too.

Comment: @Nikhil i see. Well, at the least your three way condtraint can work...its just a 1NF form.

Comment: @Nikhil I altered my response. Only the last part is unfinished....but I've spent more hours than I care to admit. :/

Comment: I really appreciate for the support which you provided. But without going into triggers or CHECK. I came to conclusion while using stored procedures and applied some if condition to filter the data.

Comment: @Nikhil nice, glad to hear that. Always enjoy the questions, as even what i think i know gets challenged. :) happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a trigger then you must normalize your tables.

1. Create a second table - say `T1_PAIRS` - that will store all permitted pairs of (col2, col3).
2. Create an unique constraint on `col2` column in table `T1_PAIRS` - this constraint allows only for unique values of `COL2` - for example no more than one `S3` value can be used in all pairs ==> this enforces the rule: "One S3 can belong to only one SX"
3. Create a primary key on `( col2, col3 )` columns in this table `T1_PAIRS`.
4. Create a foreign key constraint on `( col2, col3 )` in `T1` table that references the primary key of `T1_PAIRS` table.
5. In the end create an unique constraint on `(col1, col2, col3)` columnt to enforce a rule ==> S3 and SX as pair can belong can belong to multiple columns1's values (but no more than one value of column1)"

An example:

```
CREATE TABLE T1_PAIRS (
   Col2 varchar2(10), Col3 varchar2(10),
   CONSTRAINT T1_PAIRS_PK PRIMARY KEY( col2, col3 ),
   CONSTRAINT T1_col2_UQ UNIQUE( col2 )
);

INSERT ALL
    INTO T1_PAIRS( col2, col3 ) VALUES( 'S', 'S2' )
    INTO T1_PAIRS( col2, col3 ) VALUES( 'SX', 'S3' )   
SELECT 1 FROM dual;

ALTER TABLE T1
ADD CONSTRAINT col2_col3_pair_fk 
FOREIGN KEY ( col2, col3 ) REFERENCES T1_pairs( col2, col3 );

ALTER TABLE T1
ADD CONSTRAINT pair_can_belong_to_multi_col1 UNIQUE( col1, col2, col3 );
```

Comment: We cant create another table , as this is also the requirement. Secondly, I have already added a unique constraint on all 3 columns. Also, I want to specify the col2's value and col3's value can be null but col1's value cant be null. I will try using the triggers as commented above in the question. And thanks for the support but creating another table is not the answer needed.